# Optimizing for() loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization

my teacher said i could optimize this for() loop, but i can't see how, any help would be great

```
void vowels(char strng[])
{
int i, j, word_len, vowels_len, vowel_count;
char vowels[] =  "aeiouAEIOU";
word_len = strlen(strng);     
vowels_len = strlen(vowels);
vowel_count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < word_len; ++i) {         
    for (j = 0; j < vowels_len; ++j) {   
       if (strng[i] == vowels[j]) {
           ++vowel_count;
           break;
       }
    }
}

printf("%s: %d vowels\n", strng, vowel_count);    
}
```

Comment: instead of the inner for loop you can make a long if statement if(strng[i] == 'a' || strng[i] == 'e' ...)

Comment: Well you can learn more about loop unrolling in the book or in net, that is one of the technique for loop optimization.

Comment: Optimize for what objective? Performance, code size, maintainability, readability, compatibility?

Comment: There's also `toupper()` or `tolower()` and a `switch` statement with `case 'A': case 'E': ... vowel_count++; break;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to remove the nested loop altogether, replacing it with an array that maps character codes to a flag indicating whether or not the `char` is a vowel:

```
int isVowel[256] = {0};
for (int i = 0 ; vowels[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
    isVowel[(unsigned char)vowels[i]] = 1;
}
```

Now the main loop can be optimized as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i != word_len ; i++) {         
    vowel_count += isVowel[(unsigned char)string[i]];
}
```

You can achieve a comparable performance with a `switch` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i != word_len ; i++) {
    switch(string[i]) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            vowel_count ++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the performance using `switch` will be the same? It really depends on how aggressively the switch will be optimized.

Comment: I would hope the switch solution would have better performance as you don't have the other loop populating the `isVowel` array first?

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's true, C standard does not give any guarantees about that. However, the range from `A` to `u` in ASCII or from `a` to `U` in EBCDIC is relatively narrow, so most compilers would go with a jump table instead of a chain of `if`s.

Comment: @ChrisTurner The outer loop in the code would be replaced with whatever C uses to populate the jump table of the `switch`. It might be a smaller table, so the load would be faster, but a comparable amount of CPU cycles would be spent populating it.

Comment: It depends on how the compiler optimises the `switch` statement - I'd expect it to pre-calculate the jump table rather than generating it during run-time.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization more simplistic than Dasblinkenlight's is:

```
char vowels[] =  "AEIOU";
vowels_len = sizeof(vowels)-1;
    ...
    for (char c=strng[i]&~32, j = 0; j < vowels_len; ++j) {
        if (c == vowels[j]) {
```

(`c&~32` is toupper in ascii.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your teacher would consider this cheating, but this is one possible way to hunt for vowels that would be more optimal than using 2 nested for loops.

```
char *pos;
int vowel_count=0;

pos=strng;
while(pos)
    {
    pos=strpbrk(pos,"aeiouAEIOU");
    if(pos)
        {  
        vowel_count++;
        pos++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize code, you must first realize what's the bottlenecks. On the algorithm-level, you have the following basic performance problems:

- You must realize that `strlen` goes through the whole string in search of a null terminator and therefore you traverse the same string `strng` twice. This is inefficient - the optimal would be to check for null termination at the same time as you check the data.
- The literal `"aeiouAEIOU"` is a constant so you know the size of it at compile-time. No need to calculate this in run-time with strlen(). You could use `sizeof` instead, which is evaluated at compile-time.
- By checking for both upper case and lower case, you double the work. Instead, temporarily convert the character you look for to upper case, then only look among upper case vowels for a match.

You also have a major bug, namely that the function doesn't return the result.

The first step of "naive" manual optimization would therefore be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int vowels(const char str[])
{
  const char VOWEL_LOOKUP[] = "AEIOU";
  int vowel_count = 0;

  for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
  {
    char ch = toupper(*str);
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(VOWEL_LOOKUP)-1; i++)
    {
      if(ch == VOWEL_LOOKUP[i])
      {
        vowel_count++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return vowel_count;
}


int main (void)
{
  const char str[] = "Stack Overflow"; // 4 vowels 
  printf("%s: %d vowels\n", str, vowels(str));
}
```

---

On an advanced level, you would look at the number of branches needed for the algorithm, as these tend to kill performance the most, blocking the CPU's branch prediction.

You could then consider replacing the inner loop with a look-up table. This may or may not improve performance - but at least it will make performance deterministic. And you'll probably start to sacrifice readability at this point, so you shouldn't optimize further unless this is a known bottleneck.

A look-up table version might look something like this evil, not-recommended code, which exploits the fact that symbol tables usually list letters in alphabetic order (EBCDIC did not, so this won't compile on various wildly retarded legacy systems).

```
int vowels(const char str[])
{
  _Static_assert('Z' - 'A' == 25, "Weird symbol table."); // compile-time sanity check 
  const bool VOWEL_LOOKUP['U'-'A'+1] = // compromise between sacrificing RAM or speed
  {
    ['A'-'A'] = true,
    ['E'-'A'] = true,
    ['I'-'A'] = true,
    ['O'-'A'] = true,
    ['U'-'A'] = true,
  };
  int vowel_count = 0;

  for(; *str != '\0'; str++)
  {
    char ch = toupper(*str);
    if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'U') // always 2 branches instead of 5
    { // but comes with a bit of calculation overhead:
      ch -= 'A';
      vowel_count += (int)VOWEL_LOOKUP[(size_t)ch]; 
    }
  }

  return vowel_count;
}
```

This is not necessarily faster... always benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest thing ever.

```
void ultravowulator(const char strng[])
{
    char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int vowelscnt = strlen(vowels);    
    int vocabular[256] = {0};   

    for(; *strng != '\0'; strng++) {    
        vocabular[*strng]++;
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vowelscnt; i++){        
        total += vocabular[vowels[i]];
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}

main()
{
    char word[] = "Stack overflow";
    ultravowulator(word);
}
```